# Cannot pass DateTime parameter to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am struggling here with a very simple issue, but I have spent hours without progress.

I have this stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [Calculation_Upsert]
    @Id INT = NULL,
    @BillWho VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @ClearingBroker VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @Customer VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @EffectiveDate DATETIME = NULL,
    @ExecutingAccount VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @ExecutingBroker VARCHAR(103) = NULL,
    @Trader VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @User VARCHAR(50)
AS...
```

Trying to execute it via EF6 dbContext, but I am getting strange errors. Most of the time the exception message is " ", sometimes "cannot convert 'nvarchar' to Datetime", and others the parameter @EffectiveDate is missing. I even tried to pass null, or DBNull.Value, or as string "2023-01-13T10:00:00" or "2023-01-13 10:00:00" and does not work.

```
var sqlparams = new object[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@Id", Id),
    new SqlParameter("@BillWho", BillWho),
    new SqlParameter("@ClearingBroker",cb),
    new SqlParameter("@Customer", cus),
    new SqlParameter("@EffectiveDate", DBNull.Value), //tried also null, DateTime.UTCNow, "2023-01-13T10:00:00", "2023-01-13 10:00:00"
    new SqlParameter("@ExecutingAccount", ea),
    new SqlParameter("@ExecutingBroker", eb),
    new SqlParameter("@Trader", trader),
    new SqlParameter("@User",user)
};

try
{
```

//Method 1

```
    return await _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("[Calculation_Upsert] @Id, @BillWho, @ClearingBroker, @Customer, @EffectiveDate, @ExecutingAccount, @ExecutingBroker, @Trader, @UserNbk",
        sqlparams).ToListAsync();
```

This one returns "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError:  " and the exception message is " " when I am using DBNull.Value, or "Error convert nvarchar to DateTime" if I use DateTime.UTCNow or any string equivalent.

//Method 2

```
    _dbContext.Calculation_Upsert(Id, BillWho, cb, cus, DateTime.UtcNow, ea, eb, trader, user);
    return new List<int>() { 1 };
```

This returns "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'" but the InnerException message is " ".

//Method 3

```
    await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
        $"EXECUTE [Calculation_Upsert] @Id={Id}, @BillWho='{BillWho}', @ClearingBroker='{cb}', " +
            $"@Customer='{cus}', @EffectiveDate='2023-01-13T14:08:00', @ExecutingAccount='{ea}', @ExecutingBroker='{eb}', @Trader='{trader}', @UserNbk='{user}'"
        );
    return new List<int>() { 1 };
}
```

This one returns "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError:  " and the exception message is " ".

I also tried to update the DB schema in my Edmx diagram, issue still persists.

This code, works fine into SQL Managment Tool:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [Calculation_Upsert]
        @Id = 123,
        @BillWho = 'Customer',
        @ClearingBroker = 'Broker',
        @Customer = 'My Customer',
        @EffectiveDate = null, --'2023-01-13T14:08:00', **both values work**
        @ExecutingAccount = '12345',
        @ExecutingBroker = 'Eb',
        @Trader = 'My Trader',
        @User = 'username'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I am sure I am missing something small here, but cannot find what...

Comment: It is rather a complicated sproc, that calls other and updates/inserts to many tables, but no, it does not return any rows.

Comment: could you try `new SqlParameter("@EffectiveDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime) {  Value = DBNull.Value }` ? I wonder if the problem is because it can't infer a type from `DBNull` by itself

Comment: btw: if you're *just trying to execute raw SQL*, in many ways Dapper is more helpful than EF; EF has a lot of complications that you *just don't need*; example: `await connection.ExecuteAsync("[broker].[Calculation_Receivables_IDB_Agreement_Upsert]", new { Id = 24, BillWho = "Fred", EffectiveDate = (DateTime?)null, ...etc... }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);`

Comment: @MarcGravell thank your reply. If I use your first option, I am getting the empty message. With the dapper option, I am getting this one: " 'Procedure or function Calculation_Upsert has too many arguments specified.'"
I double checked the connection and the actual sproc in my DB and the parameters match.

Comment: Ok the `SqlQuery<int>` is the wrong method if the Sproc returns an int result code. `SqlQuery<T>` is intended to return entities from a Sproc, I'm not familiar with attempting to map a Sproc call directly from a DbContext (Method 2) which leaves Method 3. I created a simple example (SQL Server) that takes some parameters including a null-able DateTIme and inserts a row using Method 3 with an `ExecuteSqlCommand` and it works fine using static values.  Capture your formatted string for the "EXECUTE" statement and inspect, running that exact string through management studio if it doesn't work.